# Bootstrap Class not applying in layout design

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style my textbox and layout using a [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) class, but I am getting an error message and the Bootstrap class didn't work properly.

You can review the code as well as the error image below.
What is the solution?

Here I am uploading all code and error image:

[image: This is the error]

```js
@model DriveIn.Models.UsersModel

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FK_RoleID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FK_RoleID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_RoleID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10" style="color:green">
            @ViewBag.Message

        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "GetAllUsers")
</div>
```

([ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the reference scripts with the following (it may work):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```